# How to replace multiple values in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

```
$srting = "test1 test1 test2 test2 test2 test1 test1 test2";
```

How can I change `test1` values to `test2` and `test2` values to `test1` ?
When I use `str_replace` and `preg_replace` all values are changed to the last array value.
Example:

```
$pat = array();
$pat[0] = "/test1/";
$pat[1] = "/test2/";
$rep = array();
$rep[0] = "test2";
$rep[1] = "test1";
$replace = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$srting) ;
```

Result:

```
test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1
```

Comment: You can try using an intermediary, like when swapping values in variables, http://codepad.org/GpjYMMSi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "test1 test1 test2 test2 test2 test1 test1 test2";

    echo $string . "<br />";
    echo $string = strtr($string, array("test1" => "test2", "test2" => "test1"));

?>
```

Output:

```
test1 test1 test2 test2 test2 test1 test1 test2
test2 test2 test1 test1 test1 test2 test2 test1
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://codepad.org/b0dB95X5

Comment: @Rizier123 your example works well for case sensitive replacement, for case insensitive replacement it's possible to use `str_ireplace`

Comment: @ValeryViktorovsky That wasn't necessary here, but in the manual comments there is already one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#82051

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function for case insensitive replacement:

```
$text = "test1 tESt1 test2 tesT2 tEst2 tesT1 test1 test2";

$from = array('test1', 'test2', '__TMP__');
$to   = array('__TMP__', 'test1', 'test2');
$text = str_ireplace($from, $to, $text);
```

Result:

```
test2 test2 test1 test1 test1 test2 test2 test1
```

Answer (score 0):

With preg_replace you can replace test value with the temporary values then replace the temporary value with interchanged test values

```
$srting = "test1 test1 test2 test2 test2 test1 test1 test2";
$pat = array();
$pat[0] = '/test1/';
$pat[1] = '/test2/';
$rep = array();
$rep[1] = 'two';  //temporary values
$rep[0] = 'one';

$pat2 = array();
$pat2[0] = '/two/';
$pat2[1] = '/one/';
$rep2 = array();
$rep2[1] = 'test2';
$rep2[0] = 'test1';

$replace = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$srting) ;
$replace = preg_replace($pat2,$rep2,$replace) ;

echo $srting . "<br/>";
echo $replace;
```

output:

```
test1 test1 test2 test2 test2 test1 test1 test2
test2 test2 test1 test1 test1 test2 test2 test1
```